# How to add to full environment path?

Tags: environment-variables

I need to add two directories to the environment path, but when I enter the first it gets cut of in the middle. It seems to me my environment path is full(there are quite a lot of things in there).

How can I add my two directories to the environment path?

I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're working in windows.
Make 2 new environment variables.
Then add the 2 environment variables to the environment path by name like this:

```
%variable_name1%;%variable_name2%;
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows:

```
PATH="PATH1";"PATH2";%PATH%
```

In Unix:

```
PATH="PATH":"PATH":%PATH%
```

Note: Quotes are requires if path contains spaces in between like c:\Program Files\abc